# Centralizer of the absolute Galois group of a number field

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, class-field-theory

By [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/304708), we know that if $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is a finite extension, the centralizer of $G_K$ in $G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ is trivial. The argument there uses that the abelinization of $G_K$ is the pro-finite completion of $K^\times$ and that the action of $G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ is the natural one. My question is how does the situation look in the number field case? In that case (now global) class field theory gives us that
$$G_K^{ab}\cong K^\times \backslash \mathbb{I}_K/\mathcal{O}.$$
It seems that there ought to be a non-trivial element of $G_\mathbb{Q}$ which fixes an element of $\mathbb{I}_{K}$ modulo $K^\times$ and $\mathcal{O}$ not that I can give an example.... If that were the case, the centralizer would be non-trivial. Is there a good description of the centralizer or is it trivial?

Comment: Global CFT gives us an isomorphism from the abelianization of $G_K$, not $G_K$ itself.

Comment: right, that is what I meant, I'll change it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $L/K$ are number fields, then the centralizer $C_{G_K}(G_L)$ of $G_L$ in $G_K$ is trivial: As $C_{G_K}(G_L)$ is normal in the normalizer $N_{G_K}(G_L)$, the fixed field $E$ of $C_{G_K}(G_L)$ is a Galois extension of the fixed field $F$ of $N_{G_K}(G_L)$. Now $F$ lies between $K$ and $L$, in particular it is a number field. The compostium $LE$ is a finite extension of $E$ with abelian absolute Galois group. It follows from a result of Weissauer in [this](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/crll.1982.334.203/pdf) paper (see also Theorem 13.9.1 in the book Field Arithmetic by Fried-Jarden), that every proper finite extension of the Galois extension $E$ of the number field $F$ is Hilbertian, in particular its absolute Galois group is not abelian. Therefore, $LE$ has no proper finite extensions, and so $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ is a finite extension of $E$, and therefore in fact $E=\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$.

Comment: Great, thanks at lot!